# Decrypt Encrypted value

Tags: ios, encryption

In my application i am using AES Encryption and decryption to encrypt and decrypt value.When i am trying to decrypt an encrypted value, the result showing nil value. Commented Code is Encrypted
Encrypted value can be set on NSString [ secretMessage ] and send to decryption.

```
 NSString *salt_value = @"0{��\\n;S�i�S��B~";
        NSData *saltValue = [salt_value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSData *key = [BBAES keyBySaltingPassword:@"password" salt:saltValue keySize:BBAESKeySize256 numberOfIterations:65536];

        NSString *data = @"/R/MktHb1Y/bCZlVhFm8Xw==";
        NSData *pngData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:data options:1];
         NSString *secretMessage = @"9Buc9WL1o4M8a3qBsDjVSJek4HzxJMn9t57MPo/1uro=";
    //    
    //    NSString *encryptedString = [secretMessage bb_AESEncryptedStringForIV:pngData key:key options:BBAESEncryptionOptionsIncludeIV];
    //        NSLog(@"Encrypted message: %@", encryptedString);



        NSString *decryptedMessage = [secretMessage bb_AESDecryptedStringForIV:pngData key:key];
            NSLog(@"Decrypted message: %@", decryptedMessage);
```

Any Help or advice is Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: So, you use the commented code to produce encryted data?

Comment: According to your existing code snippet, it seems just to apply AES decryption to base64 encoded string, which is not proper.

Comment: Since the author of is not willing to describe the keyBySaltingPassword method don't use that project. Without a description interoperability is not really possible. Further the password must only use characters in the iso 8859-1 encoding character set, this is not realistic and not necessary.

Comment: If you want to use a 3rd party encryption library consider [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), it is currently being developed, supports several platforms, uses the current Best Practices and just does the right thing.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this link https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC and use this library. https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android is for android. We could encrypt and send data to each other. The only reservation I have is that IV is static while there didn't appear to be any salt. But it is a good starting point and own secretkeyspec and iv can be provided.

Comment: Not the worst library but it has not been updated in 3 years. It also does not support using PBKDF2 (Password Based Derivation Function) instead using SHA256,  not even an HMAC. This is no longer considered a best practice. Further the top level methods use a nil iv. RNCryptor is a much better choice.